# my upgrade pip returns an error exception

Tags: python, pip, conda, upgrade

i'm trying to upgrade my pip in conda but it retuns:

```
    ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 153, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 455, in run
    use_user_site=options.use_user_site,
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 62, in install_given_reqs
    **kwargs
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 861, in install
    use_user_site=use_user_site, pycompile=pycompile,
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 495, in move_wheel_files
    warn_script_location=warn_script_location,
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 594, in move_wheel_files
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 402, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_internal\wheel.py", line 330, in make
    return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 391, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 295, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 231, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\yurs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 370, in _get_launcher
    result = finder(distlib_package).find(name).bytes
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bytes''
```

what should i do about it?

Comment: How exactly did you run pip?

Comment: i'm just typing 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip'

Comment: Did you also try using conda's way of doing it (`conda update pip`)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+AttributeError+NoneType+object+has+no+attribute+bytes